# [HELP]Ubuntu 16.04 vs OpenVPN & Google Authenticator

Tags: networking, 16.04, openvpn, google

:-)

I tried searching for a solution to my problem, but was unable to find any, other than "it's a bug in OpenVPN".

Essentially the problem is this: OpenVPN w. Google Authenticator does not seem to work in Ubuntu 16.04. A theory I read somewhere, is that this is due to the masking that is now being done, using the * symbol. I have no idea if this is the case, but the problem is as follows:

`Fri Apr 29 10:12:04 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Feb  2 2016
Fri Apr 29 10:12:04 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Enter Auth Username: ****
Enter Auth Password: ****************
CHALLENGE: Enter Google Authenticator Code
Response: ******
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->200000] S=[212992->200000]
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]192.168.20.97:1197
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]192.168.20.97:1197, sid=cc1d9a0e 7240913e
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=OpenVPN CA
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=OpenVPN Server
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Fri Apr 29 10:12:24 2016 [OpenVPN Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]192.168.20.97:1197
Fri Apr 29 10:12:27 2016 SENT CONTROL [OpenVPN Server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Fri Apr 29 10:12:27 2016 AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED,Google Authenticator Code must be a number
Fri Apr 29 10:12:27 2016 SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting`

Specifically the problem is this:

> AUTH_FAILED,Google Authenticator Code must be a number

Just to answer the obvious question: Yes I made absolutely, positively, considerably, tremendously sure that I am using numbers and that my keyboard is actually outputting numbers :P

The OS is a complete fresh install.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I posted a temp solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openvpn/+bug/1576588?comments=all